# datetime conversion of a column results in pandas warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to convert a column in a pandas dataframe to datetime format as follows:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

Although this works as expected, pandas gives the following warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if sys.path[0] == '':
```

Is there a better way to to a datetime conversion of a pandas column that does not produce this warning?

Comment: How did you get your `df`? If it's generated from another DataFrame, then pandas is trying to watch out for you and warn you that you are only changing the column of `df` rather than the original DataFrame it came from.

Comment: datetime conversion is fine but the way df is constructed and used for modification here isn't. as Michael Cao mentions, if it's a subset of another frame (or even itself) *and* you plan to do modifications on it, better is to chain a `.copy()` at the end of its definition, i.e., `df = some_frame[...].copy()`. This explicitly makes a copy, no warnings needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get rid of the warning:

```
df.loc["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

Pandas discourages it if you set a slice of a dataset. Generally, using `.loc` is the best way to go when accessing your data.